# Removing Numbers from a String using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I remove numbers from a string using Javascript?

I am not very good with regex at all but I think I can use with replace to achieve the above?

It would actually be great if there was something JQuery offered already to do this?

```
//Something Like this??

var string = 'All23';
string.replace('REGEX', '');
```

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`\d` matches any number, so you want to replace them with an empty string:

```
string.replace(/\d+/g, '')
```

I've used the `+` modifier here so that it will match all adjacent numbers in one go, and hence require less replacing. The `g` at the end is a flag which means "global" and it means that it will replace ALL matches it finds, not just the first one.

Comment: thank you for the explanation maybe I can remember this one for the future, oh wait don't need to do that, "favourited"! :)

Comment: Will the string ever have float numbers? If so you need another regex. `"str 12.3 or 12,3".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?/g)`

Comment: The string will only have integers. Thank you for that suggestion though.

Comment: A word of caution, `"-1000".match(/\d+/g);` will return "1000" not "-1000".

Comment: If anyone tries to use @BrunoLM solution from the comment, mind that there must be a replacement argument, `"str 12.3 or 12,3".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?/g, '')`

Answer (score 4):

Just paste this into your address bar to try it out:

```
javascript:alert('abc123def456ghi'.replace(/\d+/g,''))
```

`\d` indicates a character in the range 0-9, and the `+` indicates one or more; so `\d+` matches one or more digits.  The `g` is necessary to indicate *global* matching, as opposed to quitting after the first match (the default behavior).

Comment: It needs the `g` flag otherwise it fails on "abc123def456"