# Remove all numbers including floats from string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these strings with numbers

```
"$12.3"
"12,3 SEK"
"12 pounds"
```

In all the occurrences i need to remove the number, float or not, and just keep the rest of the string.

```
"$"
"SEK"
"pounds"
```

I found several posts that are similar to my question, like this one:
[Removing Numbers from a String using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878357/removing-numbers-from-a-string-using-javascript)

Where something like this is suggested in a comment:

```
"12.3 USD".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?/g)
```

But that only returns (with the Chrome dev console):

```
"undefined USD"
```

Comment: `str = str.replace(/\d*[,.]?\d+[ \t]*/g, '');`

Comment: A simple lookup of the method `replace()` would have shown you it takes 2 arguments

Comment: The problem is, you have no idea what part of non-digits adjacent to numbers are actually part of the number. For example `%.7`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you aren't telling it what to replace those values with. Try

```
"12.3 USD".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?/g, '')
//   replace with an empty string ---^
```

It looks like you also want to remove any whitespace coming after the numbers so you could modify your regex a bit to do that.

```js
let result = "12.3 USD".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?\s*/g, '');
//                       remove whitespace ---^
console.log(result);
```